What events would you like to participate in?
We recently concluded a two week long Twitter event, which was very successful. 
Based on the response, I think it would be great if we had one to two week long events every month. If successful, these events would take RE a few steps closer to graduation. However, this means that we need a lot of good event ideas. 
So, if you have any ideas regarding events or anything interesting that you would like to see happen, go ahead and post!
Some pointers to keep in mind :

Events should have a shared aim or objective (Eg. improving wikis, sharing questions)
Events should encourage a group of people to work towards the aim at the same time (should be spread around a few days)
Events should generally be based around the site and community (Eg. edits, questions, answers, tag wikis)

In short, don't think of events as professional conferences involving 50-100 people, but rather along the lines of a group of 10-20 friends hiking for a few days (or a small user group engaging in a bug squashing session).

This is related.

@jvoisin That one is not gonna happen for quite some time, probably not until graduation.
